# Aspose Cells - Change named range reference

Tags: aspose-cells

I have a named range that current refers to A1:I8 in a worksheet. I would like to change it to refer to a larger part of the worksheet. Does anyone know of a method in Aspose that does this? Or a method that lets me delete the existing range in Aspose?

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following sample code for your reference:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("e:\\test\\Book1.xlsx");

Worksheet sheetRef = workbook.Worksheets[0];
NameCollection names = workbook.Worksheets.Names;
Name name = names["MyRange"];
name.RefersTo = "=A1:J10";
```